# Как преобразовать вертикальную запись в горизонтальную?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]    Имеется файл iplir.conf (конфиг VipNet) например такой :

```
> #commentary
[id]
id= 0x1a0e000d
name= координатор2
filterdefault= pass
ip= 192.0.2.9
ip= 192.0.2.10
tunnel= 192.0.2.201-192.0.2.202 to 192.0.2.201-192.0.2.202
firewallip= 192.0.2.11
port= 55777
proxyid= 0x00000000
usefirewall= off
fixfirewall= off
virtualip= 203.0.113.1
version= 3.0-670

#commentary
[id]
id= 0xffffffff
name= Encrypted broadcasts
filterdefault= drop
filterudp= 137, 137, pass, any
filterudp= 138, 138, pass, any
filterudp= 68, 67, pass, any
filterudp= 67, 68, pass, any
filterudp= 2046, 0-65535, pass, recv
filterudp= 2046, 2046, pass, send
filterudp= 2048, 0-65535, pass, recv
filterudp= 2050, 0-65535, pass, recv
filterudp= 2050, 2050, pass, send

[id]
id= 0xfffffffe
name= Main Filter
filterdefault= pass

[id]
id= 0x1a0e000b
name= administrator
filterdefault= pass
ip= 192.0.2.55
accessip= 203.0.113.2
firewallip= 192.0.2.6
port= 55777
proxyid= 0xfffffffe
dynamic_timeout= 0
usefirewall= on
virtualip= 203.0.113.2
version= 3.2-672

[id]
id= 0x1a0e000c
name= [comment] client1
filterdefault= pass
ip= 192.0.2.7
accessip= 203.0.113.3
firewallip= 192.0.2.8
port= 55777
proxyid= 0xfffffffe
dynamic_timeout= 0
usefirewall= on
virtualip= 203.0.113.3
version= 0.3-2

[id]
id= 0x1a0e000a
name= coordinator1
filterdefault= pass
ip= 192.0.2.51
ip= 192.0.2.3
accessip= 203.0.113.4
tunnel= 192.0.2.100-192.0.2.200 to 192.0.2.100-192.0.2.200
firewallip= 192.0.2.4
port= 55777
proxyid= 0x00000000
usefirewall= off
virtualip= 198.51.100.4
version= 3.0-670

[adapter]
name= eth1
ip= 192.0.2.9
allowtraffic= on
type= internal

[adapter]
name= eth0
ip= 192.0.2.10
allowtraffic= on
type= external

[dynamic]
dynamic_proxy= off
firewallip= 192.0.2.11
port= 55777
forward_id= 0x00000000
always_use_server= off
timeout= 25

[misc]
packettype= 4.1
timediff= 7200
warnoldautosave= on
client_pollinterval= 300
server_pollinterval= 900
iparponly= off
ifcheck_timeout= 30
ipforwarding= on
iscaggregate= on
msg_compress_level= 9
mssdecrease= 0
ciphertype= gost

[debug]
debuglevel= 3
debuglogfile= syslog:daemon.debug

[servers]
server= 0x1a0e000a, coordinator1

[virtualip]
startvirtualip= 203.0.113.1
endvirtualip= 203.0.113.4
maxvirtualip= 203.0.113.254
; Do not delete or change the following line!!!
startvirtualiphash= 0xABCDEF01

[visibility]
default= auto


секций [id] может достигать тысячи, запись параметров вертикальная, читать и анализировать не удобно, 
подскажите как преобразовать к удобному табличному виду т.е. одна строка одна [id] и параметры пошли по столбикам
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77407/discussion-on-question-by-vova-forum------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю какой-то вот такой варант:

```
var resultSet = new List<Param>();
var par = new Param();

while (var str = reader.Read())
{
  if (str.Trim() == "[id]")
    continue;

  if (processKvp(k,ref par))
  {
    resultSet.Add(par);
    par = new Param();
  }

}

public bool processKvp(string str, ref Param p)
{
if (str == "\n")  // возможно сюда нужно что-то еще добавить
return true;

 var kvp = str.Split("=");

// как пример, можно что-то другое придумать
 if (kvp.Count < 2)
throw new Exception();

switch (kvp[0])
{
case "a":
p.A = kvp[1];
break;
case "b":
p.B = kvp[1];
break;
// ..
// и т.д.
}
return false;

}

public class Param
{

public string paramA;
public string paramB;
// ...
// ...
// и так далее

}
```